# Trying to understand xargs

Tags: linux, command-line, xargs

The target is not to list `temp/run*.*` files. The target is to understand why the second command does not work.

First command:

```
find . \( -name 'temp' \) -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 -I datafind ls -ltr datafind
```

list all the files inside temp folders from actual directory

Second command:

```
find . \( -name 'temp' \) -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 -I datafind ls -ltr datafind/run*.*
```

gives *cannot access* error on every directory that worked with the previous command.

I searched and read man pages and examples but I can not find why the second command does not work. Any clue, please?

Comment: Not asked, but why not filter at find time?  `find . ! \( -name 'run*' \) -print`

Comment: Because there are other 'run*' files on other folders, I do not want to see. Also, please, target is: understand why second command does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The confusion is that wildcard characters such as `*` and `*.*` are evaluated by the shell when you type the command.

Therefore `datafind/run*.*` is evaluated by the shell and would be replaced by the filenames which match that, but it does not find any files that match.  Therefore `datafind/run*.*` is given to the `xargs` command and then it passes that right through to the `ls` command.

The `ls` command does not understand wildcard characters so it just takes its input and tries to find a file with that name.  There is no file with the name `run*.*` so you get an error *No such file or directory*.

Comment: Ohhh. Do you mean ls work is only print the data that shell has gathered? Never suspected but it matches with result :)  Thank you very much.

Comment: find . \( -name 'temp'  \)  -print0  | xargs -0 -L 1 -I datafind sh -c "ls -ltr datafind/run*.*"        Perfect. Many thanks again